# How to handle e.target.value for document.addEventListener in useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

How can I access e.target.value in useEffect?

```
useEffect(() => {
    const handleMouseUp = () => {
        // how can I access e.target.value to see
        // what was specifically clicked on the document?
    }

    document.addEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);
    return () => document.removeEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);
}, []);
```

Edit: For some more information, I want `handleMouseUp` to run every time `mouseup` happens *except* when certain buttons are clicked.

Comment: Look at [`useRef`](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useRef#manipulating-the-dom-with-a-ref)

Comment: You can also pass a parameter to your function: `const handleMouseUp = (e) => {console.log(e.target.value)}`

Comment: @paulin-crtn yes, I tried that but it only logs "undefined"

Comment: Thanks for the info, maybe the value property does not exist on MouseEvent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works just fine, but if you don't click an element that is an [`HTMLInputElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) it won't work. See [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-gfrdbf?file=App.tsx) and click the input element.